# Web API 2 Controller with Entity Framework 6 with Include

Tags: c#, sql-server, controller, entity-framework-6, webapi

I created a Web API to connect and update data in a SQL Server using
Entity Framework 6 (database-first).

I notice when I generate controllers for my table, the `Get<XXX>` function only returns the table row without including the child rows.

This I can fix using the `System.Data.Entity.Include` extension method?

However when I did a simple test to retrieve the table row and its associated child rows, I get the response

> StatusCode: 500, ReasonPhrase: 'Internal Server Error',

My code is as follows:

```
// GET: api/Fields/5
[ResponseType(typeof(Field))]
public async Task<IHttpActionResult> GetField(Guid id)
{
    Field field = await db.Fields.Include(x=>x.Layers).FirstOrDefaultAsync(i => i.FieldKey == id);

    if (field == null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }

    return Ok(field);
}
```

If I use the original generated code without the Include it works fine.

I've disabled lazy loading and proxy in the `DbContext` constructor:

```
 this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
 this.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;
```

Answer (score 0):

I found the reason
It is because the default JSON serializer cannot serialize correctly any cycle references among the entities

answer is to put

```
 var json = config.Formatters.JsonFormatter;
        json.SerializerSettings.PreserveReferencesHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects;
        config.Formatters.Remove(config.Formatters.XmlFormatter);
```

in

public static class WebApiConfig
    {
        public static void Register(HttpConfiguration config)